# how to backup partition layout?

Tags: backup, filesystems, partition, mbr

How I can backup(and restore) partition layout of the Disk along with file system types,UUIDs,labels,LVM partitions(Linux LVM) etc, plus with MBRs and VBRs etc but without actual files

I want to later restore it somewhere else and have identical filesystems and partitions and then restore files manually by my self

I need that layout backup to be small so I can't just make empty version of that partition and file systems and make raw image ...

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at partimage is probably the best result; however, if you want to take it further; you probably need to construct something yourself. I don't know of any any tools that will exactly backup & restore EVERYTHING you want.

**Partition table/block devices**

Dumping MBR partition table:

> sfdisk -d /dev/sd$X > $FILE

Restore MBR partition table:

> sfdisk /dev/sd$X < $FILE

Dumping GPT:

> sgdisk -b $FILE /dev/sd$X

Restore GPT:

> sgdisk -l $FILE /dev/sd$X

Show your block devices as a tree

> lsblk

**Logical block devices**

LVM (can recreate PV, VG, LVM structure):

> vgcfgbackup ...

> vgcfgrestore ...

**Filesystems**

Showing UUIDS & Labels:

> blkid

Show xfs parameters

> xfs_info /dev/sd$X$N

Show ext[234] parameters (look at the features line):

> dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda1

Backup & Restore XFS metadata:

> xfs_metadump -o /dev/sd$X$N FILE

> xfs_mdrestore FILE /dev/sd$X$N

Comment: `blkid` shows me UUIDs for partitions and filesystems but `sfdisk` does not include them, so they cannot be restored. This part is missing from the backup instructions here and it will prevent a system of restored files from booting. I'm in such a situation now.

Comment: @ygoe newer sfdisk absolutely does list and restore UUID for GPT partitions, I just verified with util-linux-2.36.1. It does not restore filesystem UUIDs, but those you could already change w/ tune2fs etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of the `dd` command. The only problem would be changing the UUID (if used) on the `/etc/fstab`, which you can do on recovery mode if needed; or change it to a label/device before doing the backup.